# Sorting Multidimensional array of more than one level

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I already checked other question regarding sort multidimensional array but none of them worked in my case
my array is as following and i want sort on based of id value in descending order

```
$arr = array(
49 => array(
    'id' => 65,
    'name' => 'any',
    'users' => array(
        772 => array(
            'id' => 149,
            'name' => 'any1'
        ),
        771 => array(
            'id' => 779,
            'name' => 'any2'
        ),
        45 => array(
            'id' => 259,
            'name' => 'any3'
        )   
    )
),
789 => array(
    'id' => 892,
    'name' => 'any4',
    'users' => array(
        65 => array(
            'id' => 389,
            'name' => 'any5' 
        ),
        98 => array(
            'id' => 895,
            'name' => 'any6'
            ),
        99 => array(
            'id' => 899,
            'name' => 'any7'
        )

    )
)
```

);

I tried to sort using usort function

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
return $b['id'] - $a['id'];
```

});

But my requirement is to sort parent as well as child array but this sort only parents

Comment: You would need to loop over each parent and sort each child separately since each child is it's own separate array. Perhaps it would be better to sort at the data source, such as a query, or when building the array.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn query and database things can't work in this case because ID is not coming from database other logic is behind that and other thing i also know loop will work in this case but i am not able to succeed in that

Comment: I posted an answer that would loop over and sort children. But if you are assigning id in php after the query, I would assume you could do that same calculation (or maybe it is just a join) in the query and solve this problem better. However without more code, there is nothing we can help with on that front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rules for sorting are the same for both parents and children I just defined a compare function. You just need to loop over each parent and sort the children.

```
//compare function, sorts by id in desc order
function cmp($a, $b){
    return $b['id'] - $a['id'];
}

//loop over each parent by reference so it changes the value in the parent array    
foreach($arr as &$parent){
    //sort the children
    uasort($parent['users'], 'cmp');
}
//unset the parent array so we don't overwrite the last parent later
unset($parent);

//sort the parents
uasort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hqM122

Edit: added requirement of preserving keys. Just switched usort to uasort.

Comment: it sorts but I also need to preserve keys

Comment: use uasort instead of usort then. Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hqM122, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myCallback($left,$right)
{
    return $right['id'] - $left['id'];
}

function id_sort(&$array)
{
    if (!is_array($array))
        return;
    foreach ($array as &$elem)
        if (array_key_exists('users',$elem))
            id_sort($elem['users']);
    uasort($array,'myCallback');
}

id_sort($arr);
```

This sorts parents by id in descending order, and children within those parents in descending order, recursively.